# How to accomplish a get_map_or_default like python dict.get

Tags: c++, stdmap

I want to write a function to get value of a key in a `std::map`, and if key is not in map, return a default value, very much like python's `dict.get(key, default)`.

So I wrote:

```
template <class K, class V>
const V& GetMapValueOrDefault(const typename std::map<K, V>& map_, const K& k, const V& default_)
{
    auto it = map_.find(k);
    if (it == map_.end())
        return default_;
    return it->second;
}
```

This works until I run following code:

```
std::map<int, ClassA> map_;  // map_ no contains key 1
const auto &value = GetMapValueOrDefault(map_, 1, ClassA());
// value.blablabla
```

I get an error because `GetMapValueOrDefault` returns a temporary variable to be referenced by `value`, and then the temporary variable is destroyed. So `value` is an invalid reference.

What is the correct way to write this function?

I don't want a `GetMapValueOrDefault(..., V default_)` because sometimes a copy is not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can force that `default_` is not a temporary, by making it a mutable reference.

```
template <class K, class V>
const V& GetMapValueOrDefault(const typename std::map<K, V>& map_, const K& k, V& default_)
{
    auto it = map_.find(k);
    if (it == map_.end())
        return default_;
    return it->second;
}
```